# Range.selectNodeContents function not work in Firefox but work in Chrome

Tags: javascript, firefox, dom

I using `Range.selectNodeContents` for copy contents from an element, in [**MDN doc**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents) is informed:

> The Range.selectNodeContents() sets the Range to contain the contents of a Node

Example:

```js
var source = document.getElementById("source"),
    referenceNode = document.querySelector(".foobar"),
    selection = window.getSelection();
    
source.onpaste = function () {
    setTimeout(showSource, 10);
};

document.querySelector(".copy").onclick = function () {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(referenceNode);
    
    selection.removeAllRanges();
    selection.addRange(range);
    
    document.execCommand("copy");
};

function showSource()
{
    console.log(source.innerHTML);
}
```

```css
#source {
    margin: 10px;
    border: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

```html
<button class="copy">Copy contents</button>

<div class="foobar">
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i><br>
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i><hr>
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i>
</div>

<hr>

Pasted contents in:

<div id="source" contenteditable>
</div>
```

After test in Chrome is returned:

```
<s>Foo</s>&nbsp;bar&nbsp;<i>baz</i><br><s>Foo</s>&nbsp;bar&nbsp;<i>baz</i><hr><s>Foo</s>&nbsp;bar&nbsp;<i>baz</i>
```

In Firefox is returned:

```
<div class="foobar">
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i><br>
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i><hr>
<s>Foo</s> bar <i>baz</i>
</div>
```

Note that in Chorme did not return with `<div class="foobar">`, but in Firefox came (I'm not talking about line breaks and `&nbsp;`)

Would that be a firefox BUG? Is there any way around this?

---

Notes:

- Windows 8
- Firefox 59.0.1
- Chrome 64.0.3282.186

Comment: looks like chrome copies spaces as `&nbsp;`

Comment: @RolandStarke this is the specific way Chorme works to make it easier for other richtext editors, the problem is in Firefox that it is copying the whole element as if it were using "selectNode" instead of "selectNodeContents". See MDN doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNodeContents and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Range/selectNode ... The problem is the behavior of this function.

Comment: Ah okay, it was hard to spot the difference. So the problem is the aditional `<div class="foobar">...</div>`

Comment: @RolandStarke You got it :D - So in Firefox the "selectNodeContents" function is behaving like "selectNode". If I understood the documentation, this behavior is wrong, text of the documentation about the function: `The Range.selectNodeContents() sets the Range to contain the contents of a Node`